# I am connecting to mysql database using JNDI but on execution it ends up on throwing exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, jndi

These are exceptions I'm facing

`java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Public Key Retrieval is not allowed)`

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`

Here is context.xml

```
<Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/project" 
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="25" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
               username="Shubham" password="1234abc" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/studyeasy_db?useSSL=false"/>

</Context>
```

This is servlet Demo2.java

```
package org.studyeasy;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Demo2
 */
@WebServlet("/Demo2")
public class Demo2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Resource(name="jdbc/project")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            connect = dataSource.getConnection();
            String query = "Select * from users";
            stmt = connect.createStatement();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {
                out.print(rs.getString("email"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Public Key Retrieval is not allowed)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:544)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at org.studyeasy.Demo.doGet(Demo.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:665)
    ... 27 more
```

I'm beginner please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad that you joined stack overflow. This error has nothing to do with your Java code. The error code says:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Public Key Retrieval is not allowed)
```

All you need to do is set up a username and password to connect to your database.

Comment: Hi Nicholas thankq for answering. Yes I have created database and created username and password at the time of installation of mysql community server

Comment: Are you using a public key?

Comment: What is public key i don't know?

Comment: Glad I could help!